# Show all categories in R

Tags: r, format

I have a dataset:

```
variableName<-c("Mood","Mood","Mood","HappinessIndex","HappinessIndex","HappinessIndex","HappinessIndex","weather","weather","weather","weather","weather")

order<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5)

categoryName<-c("Happy","Normal","Sad","Very Happy","Happy","Unhappy","Sad","Sunny","Cloudy","Windy","Rainy","Stormy")

df<-data.frame(variableName,order,categoryName)
```

categoryName variable explains all the categories available in each variable (which is listed in variableName.  I am now trying to produce a text file that would summarise that:

the ideal output would be a text file containing the following:

```
Mood: 1 "Happy" 2 "Normal" 3 "Sad"
Happiness Index: 1 "Very Happy" 2 "Happy" 3 "Unhappy" 4 "Sad"
weather: 1 "Sunny" 2 "Cloudy" 3 "Windy" 4 "Rainy" 5 "Stormy"
```

I am beginner user of R so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your desired output isn't clear. Is that a data frame, a list or just 3 vectors? Can you make it reproducible like you did with the provided data set? For example is `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, toString(paste(order, categoryName)), by = variableName]` gets you closer?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am trying to use the output file for further analyses therefore it needs to contain quotation marks.

Comment: I still don't understand how it should look like.

Comment: OP to my knowledge, `R` doesn't like mixed vector types of the pattern `numeric character numeric character...` The vector will be coerced to the class, character.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the expected output showed, you may use `dQuote` (Using similar syntax as @David Arenburg's code in the comments)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,paste(order, dQuote(categoryName), collapse=' '), by = variableName][,
     paste(variableName, V1, sep=": ")]
#[1] "Mood: 1 “Happy” 2 “Normal” 3 “Sad”"                          
#[2] "HappinessIndex: 1 “Very Happy” 2 “Happy” 3 “Unhappy” 4 “Sad”"
#[3] "weather: 1 “Sunny” 2 “Cloudy” 3 “Windy” 4 “Rainy” 5 “Stormy”"
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(variableName) %>%
  summarise(V1= paste(order, dQuote(categoryName), collapse= ' ')) %>% 
  transmute(V1= paste(variableName, V1, sep=": "))
```

Comment: I guess we can improve data.table solution using `do.call(paste, ...)`. what do you say?

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  I did thought about that, but then we need to summarise with the by groups.  May be the last part can be `do.call`, but there is only two columns, so I left it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in follow-up to Akrun's data.table solution

```
do.call(paste, 
c(setDT(df)[,  list(variable=paste(order, dQuote(categoryName), 
      collapse=' ')), by=variableName], sep = ": "))

#[1] "Mood: 1 “Happy” 2 “Normal” 3 “Sad”"                          
#[2] "HappinessIndex: 1 “Very Happy” 2 “Happy” 3 “Unhappy” 4 “Sad”"
#[3] "weather: 1 “Sunny” 2 “Cloudy” 3 “Windy” 4 “Rainy” 5 “Stormy”"
```

Comment: The reason is that it gave a feeling that you were creating a column inside (which indeed was). but, the `paste` actually figured it out from the column name i.e. `sep`